# XSLT template to find occurence into response data

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In an XSLT 2.0 tranformation I have 2 input :

Fist Input my initial payload :

```
<datas>
   <data1>1000</data1>
   <data2>2000</data2>
   <data3>1000</data3>
   <name1>1000</name1>
   <name2>1000</name2>
</datas>
```

Second input is a result an of transcodification service

```
<results>
  <result>
   <type>data<type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>john</value>
  <result>
  <result>
   <type>data<type>
   <key>2000</key>
   <value>tom</value>
  <result>
  <result>
   <type>name<type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>marc</value>
  <result>
  <result>
   <type>data<type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>john</value>
  <result>     
  <result>
   <type>name<type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>marc</value>
  <result>
 </results>
```

In need as output

```
<datas>
  <data1>john</data1>
  <data2>tom</data2>
  <data3>john</data3>
  <name1>marc</name1>
  <name2>marc</name2>
</datas>
```

In want to create a xslt template to map reponse without run trough all datas each time. The results order is not the same of the input datas

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A short solution that doesn't depend on position, doesn't use any non-global variables**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kResByChildren" match="value"
  use="concat(../type, '+', ../key)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDocResults" select=
   "document('file:///c:/temp/delete/results.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::text())]|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "key('kResByChildren', concat(substring(name(..),1,4), '+', .),
                                $vDocResults)[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<datas>
   <data1>1000</data1>
   <data2>2000</data2>
   <data3>1000</data3>
   <name1>1000</name1>
   <name2>1000</name2>
</datas>
```

**and the second provided document (with all malformities corrected) resides in the file `c:\temp\delete\results.xml`:**

```
<results>
  <result>
   <type>data</type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>john</value>
  </result>
  <result>
   <type>data</type>
   <key>2000</key>
   <value>tom</value>
  </result>
  <result>
   <type>name</type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>marc</value>
  </result>
  <result>
   <type>data</type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>john</value>
  </result>
  <result>
   <type>name</type>
   <key>1000</key>
   <value>marc</value>
  </result>
 </results>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<datas>
   <data1>john</data1>
   <data2>tom</data2>
   <data3>john</data3>
   <name1>marc</name1>
   <name2>marc</name2>
</datas>
```

**Explanation**: Use of a compound key.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is first match the child elements of the **data** element on your first XML document

```
<xsl:template match="datas/*">
```

Then extract the 'type' and 'position' of the element into variables

```
<xsl:variable name="type" select="substring(local-name(), 1, 4)" />
<xsl:variable name="position" select="number(substring(local-name(), 5))" />
```

Finally, you could look up the relevant name in the second document (which I am calling 'test2.xml' in my example) like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('test2.xml')/results/result[type=$type][position()=$position]/value/text()" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="datas/*">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring(local-name(), 1, 4)" />
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="number(substring(local-name(), 5))" />
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="document('test2.xml')/results/result[type=$type][position()=$position]/value/text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following should be output

```
<datas>
   <data1>john</data1>
   <data2>tom</data2>
   <data3>john</data3>
   <name1>marc</name1>
   <name2>marc</name2>
</datas>
```

EDIT: As Martin Honnen rightly pointed out in the comments (Thanks Martin!), this would better achieved with a key. First define a key like so:

```
 <xsl:key name="lookup" match="result" use="type" />
```

Then you could look up the text from the second document like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates
     select="key('lookup', $type, document('test2.xml'))[$position]/value/text()" />
```

This XSLT should also work (in XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="lookup" match="result" use="type" />

    <xsl:template match="datas/*">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring(local-name(), 1, 4)" />
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="number(substring(local-name(), 5))" />
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates
                select="key('lookup', $type, document('test2.xml'))[$position]/value/text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `result[type=$type]` asks for using a key (which is possible with question being tagged as XSLT 2.0 and that having `key('key-name', keyvalue, $key-doc)`), no?

Comment: Yes! My brains was not in gear... But I have amended my answer to show the better approach using the key in XSLT 2.0.